# Increase padding in gnome terminal

Tags: command-line, gui, gnome-terminal

I'd like to increase the padding in the gnome terminal, because the default has **no** padding and hurts my eyes.

Padding as in: I want space between the window border and where the text input/output is displayed.

For example:

```
=[X][-][ ]=============My Terminal==================
|                                                  |
|  $> echo "Padding occurs on both sides for long  |
|     input"                                       |
|                                                  |
|                                                  |
|                                                  |
====================================================
```

Answer (score 59):

[paulusm](https://askubuntu.com/a/441002/349837) was mostly right. This expanded solution works as of **Ubuntu 14.04.1** with **GNOME Terminal 3.6.2**.

### For all versions

1. Add the following code to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

   ```css
    VteTerminal,
    TerminalScreen,
    vte-terminal {
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        -VteTerminal-inner-border: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }
   ```

   You will need to create the file if it does not already exist.
2. Kill all instances of gnome-terminal:

   ```
   killall gnome-terminal
   ```
3. Restart gnome-terminal.

As of Ubuntu 18.04, you need to add one more element selector for this to work.

Comment: The specified gtk.css file did not exist on my system. I had to create it (and then the solution worked).

Comment: This works perfectly in pantheon-terminal (elementary OS Loki) as well.

Comment: If you have TRouBLe remembering how those numbers relate to edges, it's Top Right Bottom Left.

Comment: @TerryBrown TRouBLe is a nice way. Another is think of hands progressing on an analog clock: 12-3-6-9 (Top, Right, Bottom, Left).

Comment: Skipping ahead to 2022, still works great with both gnome-terminal and terminator on Debian 11. Thanks a bunch, I really enjoyed the inner gap feature of Alacritty, perfect to see it's doable for a tiled terminal such as Terminator! Cheers

Comment: August 2022 and worked fine on Linux Mint 20.2 Uma

Answer (score 15):

I tried all answers here on Ubuntu 16.10 with gnome-terminal 3.20.2 and they didn't work. I found the up-to-date solution in [this launchpad thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1472689). In the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` (which you may need to create), add this:

```
vte-terminal {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this also works for Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Works in 17.10.

Comment: So, do I create gtk.css to only have your 3 lines? Or, how can I create a default one?

Comment: @RobinHsu if the file exists, add this to the end. If it doesn't, create it, and only add this.

Comment: This is not working on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Working on Arch

Comment: for me this is working with ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 4):

To move the terminal output away from the window borders create the stylesheet ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css with the following setting:

```
TerminalScreen {
 -VteTerminal-inner-border: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=163964

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with some terminals, for example old xterm

```
xterm -b 10 -title "-b 10" -e nano &
xterm -title "no border spec" -e nano &
```

In the manual
`man xterm` you find how to set fonts, foreground and background colours. Maybe a little tricky to configure, but *very* flexible.

Answer (score 3):

Please go through this issue - [Unity Terminal 16.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1472689/comments/5)

The Comment on the Wishlist describes is very proper solutions for Ubuntu 16.04 Terminals, where we need to change file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```
VteTerminal,
TerminalScreen {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -VteTerminal-inner-border: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

**TO**

```
VteTerminal {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

`padding` works the same as normal CSS `padding`.

Comment: This is not working on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the old days there used to be [X Resources](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources). Creating a `.Xdefaults` or `.Xresources` file in your home directory you could change all sorts of settings for graphical applications.

System wide defaults on my box are found in `/etc/X11/Xresources` and `/etc/X11/app-defaults` but i don't know if gnome-terminal cares for any of those.

*Edit*: also, this seems "theme department", so editing theme files or starting gnome-terminal with a custom `.gtkrc` file could do the trick, something like

```
$ GTK2_RC_FILES=~/custom-gtkrc gnome-terminal
```

in the terminal, or editing the gnome-terminal.destktop above to look like

```
Exec=env GTK2_RC_FILES=/home/you/custom-gtkrc gnome-terminal
```

could work.

Answer (score 2):

### Updated for Ubuntu 22.10 - missing `gtk.css` file

When I went to `~/.config/gtk-3.0`, I couldn't find a `gtk.css` file. If this is what you're struggling with, here's what you should do:

1. Open a terminal window. On Ubuntu, you can use the shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+T`.
2. Type `cd ~/.config/gtk-3.0`. This will bring you to the folder where we'll make `gtk.css`. The `~` tilde represents the root directory, or `/home` in Ubuntu.
3. Type `> gtk.css` into the terminal. This will create a file called `gtk.css`, where you'll be able to make changes.
4. Open the `gtk.css` file in your preferred text editor.
5. Make whatever changes you want to the css. To increase the padding, add this:

```css
 VteTerminal,
 TerminalScreen,
 vte-terminal {
     padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
     -VteTerminal-inner-border: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 }
```

6. Save, exit, and reload the terminal.

The changes should now appear when you open a new terminal window.

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/846288/

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a padding parameter in the gconf or dconf editor. I did a search on "terminal" with the Software Center and found a number of terminal applications. Gnome used to make it easy to specify different terminal applications but things have changed a bit. /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop is where the terminal application to execute is specified. Open that file and you'll find:

```
[New Shortcut Group]
Name=New Terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

The Exec=gnome-terminal can be changed to select a different terminal application. Editing this file is a little involved because their mime type isn't recognized by naultilus as editable. You'll need to initiate the edit from the command line as follows:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
```

Having made that change the terminal application can be initiated the same as before but your alternative terminal application will be run.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I've used the workaround where you change the theme's (metacity 2) `left_width` parameter to `15` or `20` pixels.

This makes the window border thick on the left side and moves the effective left margin inside the window.  This works okay for me as the window border color and background color for the terminal are close.

I researched this thoroughly and the only other way to do it is to switch to the `xterm` terminal as mentioned above. However, configuring xterm is a pain and has to be done through the `.Xresources` config file, there is no menu with xterm.