# Is it possible to move the content view of terminal to the center while full screen the window?

Tags: command-line

I know I can use Ctrl + shift + '+' to change the font size.

But now as my code are on show on the left-side, I want to move them to center.

By drag the window I can do so, but that will show the background under the terminal 
window.

Can I move my code view to the center while the terminal is fullscreen? How?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is changing terminal to something that supports multiple, tiled terminals. In my case the easiest way is through `terminator` (which is an alternative terminal application). Just surround your active terminal with other terminals:

[image]

Or you could do it session-side with a multiplexer like `tmux`. I don't have any experience there so you'll have to play on your own.

Or you can [add padding to your terminals](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115762/increase-padding-in-gnome-terminal). Some of the Gnomier options use a form of CSS so you might even be able to add a variable amount (like `10%`)... Worth a play if this is something you're really after.