# Per-application GTK3 theme

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

On my Ubuntu 17.10, I want to be able to launch the `gnome-terminal` app with either a large padding (for full screen usage) or no padding at all (for windowed usage).

I was able to apply padding via this answer on Stack Overflow: https://askubuntu.com/a/887616/425695 .
The trick is to have the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` being:

```
vte-terminal {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

However now **all** my terminals have padding,
and I want to be able to choose between padding or no padding.

One hack would be to change `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` on the fly just before launching a terminal,
but that's really dirty.

Another option would be to give GTK an environemtn variable, as we can see in on archlinux [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK%2B#Themes) or on [this article](http://twicetwo.com/blog/linux/gtk/theme/customization/2016/05/04/per-user-gtk-customization.html):

```
$ GTK_THEME=<theme name> gnome-terminal
```

The problem is: **GNOME seems to ignore any theme I pass this way**

The following examples launches two times a terminal with the normal theme instead of the "HighContrast" one:

```
$ ls /usr/share/themes/
Ambiance/         Default/          Emacs/            HighContrast/     my-special-theme/ Radiance/         Raleigh/
$ GTK_THEME=HighContrast gnome-terminal
Warning: DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID not set and no fallback available.
$ GTK_THEME=/usr/share/themes/HighContrast/ gnome-terminal
Warning: DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID not set and no fallback available.
```

What am I doing wrong?

## EDIT 2018-10-25 After @DKBose's comment

OK, it works with 'gedit':

```
$ GTK_THEME=HighContrast gedit
```

At least now we know why it didn't work with `gnome-terminal`...
But now it's going to be harder to do what I want to do.

I guess I'll have to use another terminal emulator?
I guess `urxvt` must have an option for that?

Comment: IIRC, there maybe some GTK3 applications that just won't accept `GTK_THEME`. Please try some application other than gnome-terminal to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `gnome-terminal` ignores `GTK_THEME` as [DK Bose suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969075/per-application-gtk3-theme/969189#comment1552006_969075).