# Add Padding to Gnome Terminal

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

Maybe I've just messed something up somewhere or there is now a different CSS class for creating padding in gnome terminal, but I can't get it to pad. I tried the numerous solutions on this page:

[increase padding in gnome terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115762/increase-padding-in-gnome-terminal)

But none of they have made the padding work. The most recent answer says to use:

```
vte-terminal {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

...but to no joy. Is there now a different way?

I just came back to ubuntu after a year away, and I also notice that there is no option to set an image as the background to gnome terminal, which there used to be in the preferences.

Comment: Have you also checked this?: [Per-application GTK3 theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969075/per-application-gtk3-theme)

Comment: Yep I saw that, but that is based on the OP actually getting the padding to work first with the css, but then that padded all his terminals. I can't get the css to work.

Comment: UPDATE. I used the css code provided by Terrance below and while it didn't work for my gnome terminal, it did create padding in my termite terminal. Terrance has deleted his answer since.

Comment: Interesting, I have a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, and I have no `gtk.css` in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/`. I was wondering if you tried to search for the file `gtk.css` in your hard drive, maybe the file is located in another folder, I found these on my system:
1) `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`,
2) `/usr/share/themes/HighContrast/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`,
3) `/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

Comment: I did a system wide `find` -  only the `gtk.css` I created turned up. So that's strange. I am using 16.04, I wanted to update my post about that but it doesn't seem to have an edit option like my stackoverflow account does. And also weird thing is, as I said in previous comment, the css works for Termite terminal but not gnome - go figure!

Comment: Try with the `locate` command, first execute `sudo updatedb`, and after this command finishes, try with `locate gtk.css`.

Comment: I can undelete my answer here.

Comment: Ok I first ran `sudo updatedb` then `locate gtk.css` but still only show the `gtk.css` files I created  in both `gtk-2.0` and `gtk-3.0` plus `gtk.css` files for themes `radiance`,  `Adwaita` etc. Nothing else

Comment: Edited the gtk.css of the theme I am using too, just in case that made any difference, but nothing.

Comment: Mmmmm, really weird, do you have installed `Ubuntu Tweak` or `Unity Tweak`, if not, then install them, and try them out, it is the last resource I can imagine by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with where you add that into the `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` file.  I am assuming that your file has more lines in it, here is an example of what I did so mine has padding:

*This starts about line 93 in the file.*

```
panel-off */

VteTerminal, vte-terminal {
        padding: 10px;
}

/* menu-off
```

Or you can add it at the very bottom of the file after `/* End custom styles */`

```
/* End custom styles */
VteTerminal, vte-terminal {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The `panel-off` and `menu-off` lines were already there.  I just added my lines between those because I am assuming that the `*/` and `/*` are ends and beginnings to sections in the file.

Save your file, close all gnome-terminal windows.  Then relaunch.

**EDIT:** Also reinstalling `gnome-terminal` helped.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-terminal
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep it's in that file, but I did not have a `gtk.css` file to begin with so I created it. see here https://imgur.com/a/RPu08

Comment: @DarrenHaynes Interesting.  It is definitely working for me here.  https://imgur.com/hKh1xX5 and https://imgur.com/DYwYUgV  I am also running Xubuntu 16.04, which I can't seem to find info if GTK3 is supported in it.

Comment: Yep, I think I may have messed something up somewhere when I previously installed termite terminal.

Comment: @DarrenHaynes I have no idea on that one.

Comment: I think probably not that since your code worked to actually create padding for termite but not gnome-terminal :)

Comment: @DarrenHaynes Interesting.  I just installed termite and indeed the padding works there as well.  Maybe try reinstalling `gnome-terminal`?  `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-terminal`

Comment: Ok, so I did a reinstall and a reboot, and now the padding works.  Awesome. Still a bit miffed about what wasn't working, but all good now. Your code snippet actually provides the padding, so I will make your answer accepted,  especially as it the updated css classes compared to the older link that I pointed to in the opening post.

Comment: @DarrenHaynes I agree with you!  Sometimes it is always nice to know what happened and what exactly is causing something to not work.  But I am glad that it is working for you now.  =)

Comment: I need to remember not to write comments when I am on cough syrup.  That did not make sense.  Oops!