# Fixing increased line height/padding in terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, fonts, 22.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu 20.04. I noticed in the terminal that it is now taller because there seems to be more padding within the character cells, or some slight rendering difference in the font. I'm using Consolas, which has worked great for me before.

Before (taken from a screen recording, so it's a little fuzzy):

[image]

After (regular screenshot):

[image]

Comparison with VSCode, which has more aesthetically pleasing font spacing (and custom line height setting):

[image]

It's subtle, but you can see that each line takes up more space and the character cells are less compact. It also seems that the glyph strokes are thinner. That's probably my biggest problem.

I can't make the grid cells smaller in the Gnome terminal config, because they are already at 1.0x1.0 (and you can't go less than that). I've adjusted the font size, but it either makes the font less tall or it shrinks everything too much. I mucked around with a gtk.css (https://askubuntu.com/a/887616/152222) in my home dir to try to see if I could adjust it, but no luck. I think it may actually be a font engine issue. I wish it didn't change radically with every release, especially with no controls to adjust it.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Consolas in both the terminal and the editor?

Have you tried using a different terminal emulator?

Comment: @MDeBusk Both are using Consolas, though VSCode does have its own font rendering and scale settings.

Comment: Hi @siride, I faced the same issue today. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @soi4 I found an issue on GitLab that basically confirmed this was intentionally and probably wouldn't change: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/issues/347 and https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/issues/351.